# Потокобезопасность Collections.synchronizedList

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

Какой смысл потокобезопасности Collections.synchronizedList если ее все равно нужно синхронизировать при итерации. Вот CopyOnWriteArrayList не нужно синхронизировать + он никогда не бросает ConcurrentModificationException. Если можно, пример где Collections.synchronizedList имеет смысл использовать взамен обычного ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections.synchronizedList в сравнении с ArrayList имеет синхронизированные операции add, remove и т.п. Но итератор в данном случае не синхронизирован. Поэтому, при использовании итератора, synchronizedList нужно обязательно синхронизировать вручную.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
...
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Синхронизированный итератор
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());   
}
```

CopyOnWriteArrayList действительно полностью синхронизирован, в том числе для итератора. Что именно использовать - зависит от логики приложения и личных предпочтений.